# Number Theory: Prove there are infinite such numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Show that there are infinitely many $x$ ($x$ is element of natural nos.) for which $n^4 + x$ is not a prime for any $n$ ($n$ is element of natural nos.).

Source:
Challenge and thrill of pre college mathematics

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should not just copy-paste questions. Share your work/thoughts on the problem or point out any specific query if you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have read this book. It was recommended  to me a few years ago.

Whenever $x = 4b^4$ for a natural number $b$. 
$$
n^4+4b^4 = (n^2+2b^2)^2 - (2nb)^2 = (n^2 + 2b^2-2nb)(n^2+2b^2+2nb)
$$

Thus, there are infinitely many $x$.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I don't know the name of this factorisation. And thank you for correcting the mistake, Peter.

Comment: This is a kind of Aurifeuillean factorisation. I love the name.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: The identity is by Sophie Germain. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain#Honors_in_number_theory).

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Try to factorise when $x = 4a^4$